# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "desmoldar" y "desmoldear"? ¿En qué ámbitos se usa el segundo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, vocabulario-técnico

Ayer fui a comerme un flan y me sorprendió la palabra usada en la tapa para la acción de extraer el flan del molde:

[image]

Yo conocía la palabra "desmoldar", pero no "desmoldear", así que fui a buscar ambas al DLE. Me encuentro lo siguiente:

> **[desmoldar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DCA9Lwn)**
>
> 1. tr. Sacar algo, como un pastel o una pieza de fundición, del molde en que se ha hecho.
>
> **[desmoldear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DCDYDGL)**
>
> 1. tr. *Tecnol.* Extraer una pieza de su molde, deshaciendo este.

Entiendo que la palabra "desmoldar" se usa en repostería, dado que el DLE cita un pastel como ejemplo, mientras que "desmoldear" se usa en ámbitos tecnológicos y con la particularidad de que se tiene que romper el molde para sacar la pieza.

En el caso del flan, en primer lugar es algo relacionado con la repostería, no con la tecnología, y en segundo lugar no es necesario romper el molde para sacar el flan (creo, la verdad es que no probé a desmoldarlo en este caso, pero normalmente no suele ser necesario).

Así pues, ¿se puede considerar este caso un ejemplo de exceso de corrección? ¿Se ha intentado usar una palabra más técnica cuando lo fácil (usar "desmoldar") habría sido lo correcto? ¿Es el hecho de "romper el molde" la única diferencia entre ambas, o hay otras diferencias en la práctica? ¿En qué contextos es correcto usar "desmoldear"?

---

[Estadísticas de NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=desmoldar%2BDesmoldar%2Cdesmoldear%2BDesmoldear&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28desmoldar%20%2B%20Desmoldar%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28desmoldear%20%2B%20Desmoldear%29%3B%2Cc0) hacia 2008:

- "Desmoldar": aprox. 5-6 casos por millón de palabras.
- "Desmoldear": aprox. 0,2 casos por millón de palabras.

Comment: Hope your puzzlement did not spoil your enjoyment of your meal.

Comment: @mdewey No, it didn't. :-) In fact it added more enjoyment as I started planning a new question on this site. :-D

Comment: yo creo que con la información que has aportado has contestado a tu propia pregunta. Uno es un término culinario y el otro como indica el DLE del área tecnológica. Y la diferencia entre las dos está clara en las definiciones. Por otra parte yo nunca habia oído la palabra *desmoldear*

Comment: @blonfu a ver, yo creo que sí, que casi me autorrespondo, pero quería confirmación de alguien que entendiera más del tema. Yo sé algo de repostería y siempre he visto "desmoldar", pero no sé si a lo mejor últimamente el término "desmoldear" se está empezando a usar fuera del ámbito tecnológico.

Comment: buscando en google «"desmoldar" reposteria» 143.000 resultados «"desmoldear" repostería» 2.260. Parece que se usa pero poco, yo diría que es más bien un mal uso de la palabra. Si buscamos por la acción se usa mucho *desmoldeo* (desmoldear) cuando debería ser *desmolde* (desmoldar)

Comment: Con el tiempo, en el DLE tendrán que incluir "desmoldar" como otro significado de "desmoldear", dado que la gente lo está empezando a usar "desmoldear" como sinónimo de "desmoldar".

Comment: ¿Podría ser análogo a la situación con *chequear* y *checar*?

Answer (score 2):

Según esas definiciones, la única diferencia sería que "desmoldar" conserva el molde, mientras que "desmoldear" lo rompe. ¿No?

Pues me da que aquí **la que se ha columpiado un poco puede haber sido la RAE**. Argumentos:

- No hay usos de "desmoldear" en los corpus de la Academia que justifiquen tal definición.

  - En el CORDE solo hay [3 casos](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=desmoldear&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000): dos recetas de cocina y un tratado de mecánica, y ni uno solo de ellos dice nada de romper el molde. Si buscamos por "desmolde*" ampliamos a [15 casos](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=desmolde*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000), pero sigue sin haber referencias a romper ningún molde.
  - Idem para [el único ejemplo](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=030518%5C014%5CC000O03052018143114234.1204.1200&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20desmoldear%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCREA%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0) que aparece en el CREA (otra receta).
  - Idem para los 20 casos que se pueden hallar en el [CDH](http://web.frl.es/CNDHE) si buscamos por lema. En realidad se corresponden con los mismos documentos que aparecen en CORDE y CREA, pero incluyendo conjugaciones y variantes.
  - Y en el [CORPES XXI](http://web.frl.es/CORPES/view/inicioExterno.view), que también incluye variantes, ni siquiera hay registros de la palabra.
- No hay notas en el [Fichero General](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html) sobre "desmoldear". Sí las hay sobre "[desmoldeo](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_D/LETRA_D_PDF/DESMOLDEO/0002.pdf)" [PDF], pero ninguna aporta gran información al respecto, y no he podido consultar los libros referenciados (he encontrado el *Diccionario de la Administración* de Alcubillas, pero no su apéndice; tampoco hallé el catálogo de la Feria de Muestras de Zaragoza de 1962).
- No hay entradas en el [NTTLE](http://buscon.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) para "desmoldear", luego debe ser una incorporación reciente ([de 2014 según el DIRAE](https://dirae.es/palabras/desmoldear)); pero esto no casa con las cero apariciones en el CORPES XXI ni tampoco con que casi todas las obras referidas arriba sean de la primera mitad del siglo pasado.

De lo anterior tenemos que la RAE no ofrece material alguno que justifique su propia decisión de diferenciar las definiciones de "desmoldear" y "desmoldar".

Pero es que, si nos vamos a recursos no académicos, podemos encontrar:

- Muchos ejemplos de usos de "desmoldear", en el sentido de "desmoldar", en obras de ámbito artístico y tecnológico ([búsqueda en Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22desmoldear%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_es)).
- Diccionarios extranjeros (ej. [*Diccionario Lagenscheidt de tecnología*](https://books.google.es/books?id=ILuTMD81z7AC&lpg=PA297&ots=IbEj5lSc2L&dq=%22desmoldear%22%20tecnolog%C3%ADa&hl=es&pg=PA297#v=onepage&q&f=false)) que dan "desmoldear" y "desmoldar" como sinónimas.
- Ningún resultado en [corpus no oficiales](http://www.corpusdelespanol.org).

**Resumiendo**: el verbo "desmoldear" lleva más de 100 años usándose en castellano con el mismo significado que "desmoldar" y en los mismos ámbitos, y no hay en los corpus públicamente accesibles ningún registro escrito de otro uso que no sea ese, o al menos yo no he encontrado ninguno.

¿Es posible que en algún documento o campo específico se usen ambos "desmoldear" y "desmoldar" haciendo esa distinción que muestra el DLE? Posible es, pero desde luego no debe ser un campo muy común, viendo la falta de ejemplos.

En mi opinión, la definición actual que da el DLE para "desmoldear" no refleja en absoluto el significado real que le dan los hablantes de español. Si estuviésemos hablando de un arcaísmo que ha cambiado su definición, podría comprenderse, pero esta palabra apenas lleva 4 años en el diccionario. Y por eso creo que, en este caso, la que se ha equivocado es la RAE.