# ¿Por qué en República Dominicana se llama "suape" a la fregona y "suapear" o "suapiar" a fregar?

Tags: etimología, verbos, sustantivos, república-dominicana

Leo en [La fiesta del Chivo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_fiesta_del_Chivo_(novela)) (2000), de Mario Vargas Llosa:

> A lo lejos, en la periferia del Palacio Nacional, (...) sentía a los encargados de la limpieza, **suapeando**, barriendo, encerando, sacudiendo.

La palabra *suapear* nunca la había oído y resulta que es solamente propia de República Dominicana, el país donde transcurre la novela. El DAMER lo indica:

> [**suapear**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=suapear)
> tr. RD. Limpiar el suelo utilizando un suape.

Y luego:

> [**suape**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=suape)
> I.  1.  m. RD. Utensilio para limpiar el suelo formado por un mango largo con un manojo de tiras hechas de un tejido absorbente.
> II. 1.  m. RD. Borrachera.

Vaya, que un *suape* vendría a ser lo que llamamos [*fregona*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IRNGf4j) en España (y parece que en toda Hispanoamérica, según se lee en el DLE *3. f. Utensilio para fregar los suelos sin necesidad de arrodillarse*, sin ninguna anotación sobre un uso localizado).

En una [lista de dominicanismos](http://dominicanaonline.org/Portal/espanol/txt_dominicanismos_backup.html) veo que efectivamente referencian esta y otras muchas palabras:

> **suape** Instrumento para la limpieza de los pisos. También se dice que alguien tiene un “suape” después de haber bebido mucho.
>
> **suapear/suapiar** Trapear.
>
> **“suapiar o trapiar el piso alguien”** Insultar y recriminar a una persona sin darle oportunidad de que se defienda.

Donde [*trapear*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aO1KjHj) quiere decir *fregar el suelo con trapo o estropajo* en toda Hispanoamérica, pero también insultar o reprender en algún país (no en República Domincana).

Dicho todo lo cual, la duda es: ¿cuál es el origen de llamar *suape* a la fregona? Suena a anglicismo, pero no se me ocurre ninguno.

Comment: No está mal, yo buscando inspiración [en los flanes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25798/12637) y tú en las novelas de Vargas Llosa. :-D

Comment: Suena a un caso de espanglich. Calco de [to sweep](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Asweep).

Comment: Concuerdo  con @Rafael, he escuchado usos similares para "mapear" o "mapeador" para referirse a lo mismo por la espanglishacion de ""mop"

Comment: Ya que la República Dominicana es una isla, y *swab* es el término que se usa en los barcos, y *sweep* no incluye agua ni humedad de ningún tipo, y *swab* se oye más cercano a *suapear*,  a mí me convence la respuesta borrada de @yotanka.

Answer (score 5):

Quizás un anglicismo a partir de [**swab**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swab?q=SWAB)

> to wash a surface, especially the open, flat areas of a ship, with a wet cloth or mop

Comment: [Aquí](http://culturaylinguistica.blogspot.com.es/2010/02/dominicanismos-suape.html) se sugiere que proviene del inglés 'sweep': `Sobre el origen y la etimología del término, porque ovbiamente no es castellano, tampoco existe mucha información. Pero la fonología de la palabra y su uso sugieren que su origen puede basarse en la palabra sweep [suip] del inglés, la cual significa barrer o de sweeper [suiper] que significa quien barre o el instrumento con el cual se barre. Como barrer y suapear son acciones similares, la palabra en cuestión puede que sea un anglicismo de la palabra Sweep.`

Answer (score 3):

En una [respuesta ahora eliminada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25800/1674) por su autor, [ukemi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/18348/ukemi) indicó un origen que encontró en [Dominicanismos- Suape](http://culturaylinguistica.blogspot.com.es/2010/02/dominicanismos-suape.html):

> Sobre el origen y la etimología del término, porque ovbiamente no es castellano, tampoco existe mucha información. Pero la fonología de la palabra y su uso sugieren que su origen puede basarse en la palabra *sweep* [suip] del inglés, la cual significa barrer o de *sweeper* [suiper] que significa quien barre o el instrumento con el cual se barre. Como barrer y suapear son acciones similares, la palabra en cuestión puede que sea un anglicismo de la palabra *Sweep*.

Comment: Por supuesto, si ukemi quiere publicar respuesta, ¡que lo haga! En tal caso eliminaré esta. Publiqué para que no se perdiera esta información.

Comment: Así está bien :) si encuentro algo más concreto, escribiré una respuesta nueva.

Answer (score 0):

Yotanka puso (y luego borró) una respuesta en la que decía:

> Quizás un anglicismo a partir de [*swab*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swab?q=SWAB): "to wash a surface, especially the open, flat areas of a ship, with a wet cloth or mop."

Me parece bien, porque

- la República Dominicana es una isla
- swab es el término que se usa en los barcos
- sweep no incluye agua ni humedad
- swab se oye cercano a suapear

Por todo lo argumentado, a mí me convence la respuesta borrada.

Comment: Por supuesto, si yotanka quiere republicar su respuesta, ¡que lo haga! En tal caso borro ésta.