# ¿Qué es un vintén?

Tags: vocabulario, significado, palabras-raras, argentina, uruguay

Estoy leyendo “El Libro de Arena” (1975) de Jorge Luis Borges, y en uno de los relatos (el titulado “Avelino Arredondo”) se menciona la palabra “vintén”:

> Disponía asimismo de un tablero de ajedrez en el que jugaba partidas desordenadas que no acertaban con el fin. Le faltaba una torre que solía suplir con una bala o con un **vintén**.

He buscado online en WordReference y en la RAE (incluido el diccionario panhispánico de dudas) y no encuentro ninguna referencia a “vintén”. Lo más parecido que encontré fue un [veintén](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bRaYJY5):

> **veintén**
>
> 1. m. Escudo de oro de valor de 20 reales.

Que, aunque podría ajustarse dentro del contexto (suplía la ficha que faltaba con una moneda), no parece que sea a lo que se refiere (o al menos no a una moneda de oro de valor de 20 reales en particular).

El autor es argentino y la historia sucede en Montevideo, Uruguay. No sé si es un término específico de alguno de esos lugares.

Comment: Sí, parece que es una moneda específica de Uruguay de dos céntimos (o centésimos) de peso.

Comment: ¡Buena pregunta y bienvenido al sitio, Alvaro! Veo que en el DAMER sí aparece una referencia: [_vintén_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=vint%C3%A9n) _Ur. Ínfima cantidad de dinero_ y similares. Todo siempre referido a Uruguay. Resulta fantástico cuando los autores adaptan su lenguaje al lugar donde centran la obra y utilizan locamismos. Me pasó con [Vargas Llosa y _La fiesta del Chivo_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25799/1674)

Comment: El término vintén figura también como referencia a una moneda en la canción del musico uruguayo Alfredo Zitarrosa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En el blog [Diccionario Popular Uruguayo](http://diccionariouruguayo.blogspot.com/), hay una entrada para específica para el término "[vintén](http://diccionariouruguayo.blogspot.com/2016/06/vinten-de-cobre-equivalente-dos.html)":

> Moneda de cobre equivalente a dos céntimos de peso. Llamada así desde 1920, sucesivos cambios de signo monetario le redujeron el valor pero conservaron su nombre. También se utiliza como sinónimo de cantidad mínima de dinero. Antes de navidad los botijas uruguayos acostumbraban pedir "un vintén para el judas" (muñeco de trapo). Dicho popular: "No vale un vintén".
>
> [image: vintén uruguayo]

Entonces es una manera de referirse a una moneda de poco valor como lo sería "tostón" en México ([como indica aparente001 en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26734/14693)) o "duro" en España (una moneda de 5 pesetas).

Answer (score 5):

Por el contexto mi primera idea era que sería algún tipo de moneda, como "tostón" se usaba en México. Entonces busqué con Google (sin comillas)

> se gastó su último vintén

y apareció [un artículo del País](https://www.elpais.com.uy/informacion/politica/garcia-pintos-renuncia-partido-nacional-devolver-vinten.html): "García Pintos renuncia al Partido Nacional: "Voy a devolver hasta el último vintén"

Así que parece que sí es una moneda.

Comment: Puedes extender tu respuesta con [esta referencia](http://diccionariouruguayo.blogspot.com/2016/06/vinten-de-cobre-equivalente-dos.html). Parece que un vintén es una moneda de dos céntimos de peso.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - No, pues tú la encontraste, ponla tú en una respuesta. // ¿Podrías agregar ese diccionario a la lista, por favor?  https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/9385

Comment: al parecer es uruguaya mas que argentina

Answer (score 1):

> A la rueda rueda de pan y canela dame un vinten que me voy a la escuela

Esto es de una canción infantil uruguaya, y un *vinten* son 2 centésimos del peso de aquella época.

Comment: Hola, Piti, bienvenido al sitio. Aparte de la canción, en otras respuestas ya se ha comentado lo que es un "vintén". Si otras respuestas te parecen correctas, puedes votarlas, y añadir una nueva respuesta solo si vas a aportar nueva información. Puedes consultar las secciones [help], [tour] y [answer] para más información. Si no tienes reputación suficiente para votar, céntrate primero en aportar buenas preguntas y respuestas, y en seguida llegarás al nivel de reputación necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Está mocosa, con un hijo en los brazos para colmo, se metía en una tercera de barco y se larga a a estudiar canto a París sin un vintén en el bolsillo. Palabra "vintén" que utilizó Julio Cortázar en Rayuela. Así es como una moneda.